# Trying to search for a specific string in an array using IndexOf

Tags: c#

`string[] Dico` is an array of approximately 400000 words (one word per index).
`string[] theWord` contains the words I'm looking for.
The problem is that I always get the error `"System.String[]"` as my output:

```
 if (Array.IndexOf(Dico, theWord) >= 0)          
 {      
     Console.WriteLine("found");      
 }      
 else      
 {      
     Console.WriteLine("not found");      
 }
```

Comment: question is not clear, could you share full function? and add more details to your question?

Comment: `System.String[]` is **not** an error and that code will not result in `System.String[] ` as posted.

Comment: if Dico is string[] then theWord should be string not string[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing two `string[]` into the `Array.IndexOf()` when you should
be passing one `string[]` and one `string`. Change `theWord` from type `string[]` into a single `string` value.

`Array.IndexOf(string[], "string to find")` is what you should be doing but instead you have
`Array.IndexOf(string[], string[])` which is wrong.

The second parameter is a string that will be searched for in the array that you pass into the first parameter.